# How do I eliminate extra whitespace between macro calls in Ansible Jinja2 templates?

Tags: ansible, macros, jinja2, removing-whitespace, ansible-template

Given Ansible Jinja2 template:

```
{% macro directive(name, value) %}
{% if value is defined %}
{{ name }}={{ value }}
{% endif %}
{% endmacro -%}

# {{ ansible_managed }}

[Unit]
{{ directive('Description', service.description) }}
{{ directive('Documentation', service.documentation) }}
{{ directive('Requires', service.requires) }}
```

with `service` variable definition:

```
service:
  description: Test Template
  requires: multi-user.target
```

how can I change the template to eliminate extra newlines in resulting output:

```
# Ansible managed

[Unit]
Description=Test Template


Requires=multi-user.target
```

so that it instead looks like:

```
# Ansible managed

[Unit]
Description=Test Template
Requires=multi-user.target
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
{% macro directive(name, value) %}
{% if value is defined %}
{{ name }}={{ value }} # a newline hardcoded in macro follows
{% endif %}
{% endmacro -%}

# {{ ansible_managed }}

[Unit 1]
{{ directive('Description', service.description) }}# 1st hardcoded newline follows
{{ directive('Documentation', service.documentation) }}# 2nd hardcoded newline follows
{{ directive('Requires', service.requires) }}# 3rd hardcoded newline follows
```

It produces:

```
# Ansible managed

[Unit 1]
Description=Test Template # a newline hardcoded in macro follows
# 1st hardcoded newline follows
# 2nd hardcoded newline follows
Requires=multi-user.target # a newline hardcoded in macro follows
# 3rd hardcoded newline follows
```

Even though documentation on [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control) states "*a single trailing newline is stripped if present*", it does not apply to variable substitution, so even though the result of the macro contains a newline character at the end, this particular newline will not be stripped.

Just like it's not stripped if you define:

```
variable_with_newline: "value\n"
```

and run a template:

```
start-{{ variable_with_newline }}-end
```

it produces:

```
start-value
-end
```

---

To fix to the template either remove the hardcoded newlines:

```
[Unit]
{{ directive('Description', service.description) }}{{ directive('Documentation', service.documentation) }}{{ directive('Requires', service.requires) }}
```

or add explicit whitespace stripping:

```
[Unit]
{{ directive('Description', service.description) }}
{{- directive('Documentation', service.documentation) }}
{{- directive('Requires', service.requires) }}
```

or

```
[Unit]
{{ directive('Description', service.description) -}}
{{ directive('Documentation', service.documentation) -}}
{{ directive('Requires', service.requires) }}
```

Comment: Why does each macro reference generate  an extra space?

Comment: Yes, I meant "extra lines" or newlines. I guess I mistakenly expected Jinga2 to automatically remove the trailing newline from each macro reference, similar to what it does for each statement `{% %}`.

Comment: Note that I added the dash to `{% end macro -%}` in order to eliminate white space between the macro definition and `# {{ ansible_managed }}`.

Comment: It does impact output. It eliminates the newline between the end of the macro definition and `# {{ ansible_managed }}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the only solution may be to not use the macro. The whitespace behaviour of the macro reference seems to defeat the purpose of the macro, which is to skip a directive and its newline when the directive value is absent.

Comment: And you are somehow **obliged** to put `{% endif %}` on a separate line?

Comment: I don't know, but I want a blank line to separate the macro definition from the start of the actual visible body of the template, but not display that blank line in the output.

Comment: Jinja2 doesn't display the blank line between the macro and the rest of the template. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: On Monday, I will test it again, but I seem to recall that absent that dash in `{% endmacro -%}`, Ansible (Jinja2) did display the blank line that precedes `# {{ ansible_managed }}`.

Comment: Your second suggestion works, but the first only eliminates one of the newlines.  The very first draft of your answer (see history), where you inserted a `-` immediately after the opening braces of the second and third macro calls, also works and seems to have the same effect as placing all of the macro calls on the same line.

Comment: Well... you weren't happy with that solution at that time, but if you now want it, I'm editing the answer once again.

Comment: What made you think I was unhappy with that solution? I was surprised, actually, that you had changed it. I thought that you might have found a flaw or changed your mind. In any case, I think this version works well.